# Importing all sheet of a ODS file in R keeping the name of the sheets

Tags: r, list, dplyr, purrr, ods

I have this LibreOffice Calc (`.ods`) file ([download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BM-xo-5ui9uXgb-rHsew0kOEQvID3b4O/view?usp=sharing)).

I would like to import all the sheets of this document. In the import I will create a list, where each element of the list would be one sheet. And I would like the name of the list elements to keep the original name of sheets in the ODS file.

I created this code:

```
  library(readODS)
  library(dplyr)
  library(purrr)
  library(tidyr)

  path <- "example.ods"

  mylist <- path %>%
    ods_sheets() %>%
    set_names() %>%
    map(read_ods, skip = 1, path = path)
```

By running this code I get an error with the `set_names()` function:

```
Error in set_names(.) : 1 argument passed to 'names<-' which requires 2
```

How can I solve it to create a list with elements named as the original sheets?

Answer (score 1):

Since I am loath to download a random file from Google Drive, I set up my own example ODS file for this, with two sheets, "foo" and "bar", that look like this:

```
foo

a b
1 2
3 4

bar

a b
7 6
5 4
```

So, you had a few issues with your code. You tripped on your first one, that you need two arguments to `set_names()`. Your other issue here is that you weren't specifying **both** `.x` **and** `.f` for `map()`. We can solve these issues by using an intermediate assignment step like so:

```
library(readODS)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

path <- "test.ods"

sheets <- ods_sheets(path)
mylist <- map(seq_along(sheets), read_ods, path = path) %>%
    set_names(sheets)
mylist

$foo
  a b
1 1 2
2 3 4

$bar
  a b
1 7 6
2 5 4
```