# Importing from a LibreOffice Calc workbook

Tags: r, spreadsheet, libreoffice, r-rio

I have a LibreOffice Calc workbook with three worksheets. I'm trying to import data from the third worksheet. I've tried both the [readODS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readODS/index.html) and [rio](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rio/) packages, but they keep returning the same error message:

Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for cli; details:
call: fun(libname, pkgname)
error: object 'clic_start_thread' not found

The readODS package's get_num_sheets_in_ods and list_ods_sheets functions work as expected. But its read_ods command throws the error above.

In particular, `read_ods(path = "data/myFile.ods", sheet="Foobar", skip=2, range= "A3:E184")` throws the error message above.

OTOH, the rio package's `convert` and `import` commands, without anything fancy, also throw the error message reproduced above.

I suspect the CLI package is being used to parse commands in both packages, but I'm at a loss for how these two packages seem to be choking on the neighborhoods. How should I debug these error messages?

Comment: I know you said you didn't get the package `readODS` to work but read this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542069/importing-all-sheet-of-a-ods-file-in-r-keeping-the-name-of-the-sheets). It's not the same question, but it should help.

Comment: Thanks so much, Kat. To debug my problem, I first tried to replicate duckmayr's example. Everything worked until the mylist assignment, then I got the same error message as before!

Answer (score 0):

Kat,

Your hint led me to the solution! Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!

After I failed to replicate duckmayr's example, I realized the problem was my configuration. I searched the web for ".onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'cli' clic." While I didn't come up with anything specifically for the cli package, I came across several cases in which the solution was to reinstall or reconfigure the offending package.

So, I tried running **install.packages("cli")**, and this fixed the problem.

Funny how knowing what the solution is *not* can lead to understanding what the solution *is.*

Comment: Awesome! It's even better when you figure it out on your own.